How to get user details like DoB, Gender, Surname etc from google while login with google login in ASP.NET Core
How to get user details like DoB, Gender, Surname etc from google while login with google login in ASP.NET Core? And how to add scope for getting these details?
I am trying to get the details but it returns null and if trying to add scope then give me 403 error..
options.Scope.Add("profile");
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("email");
options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");
options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read");

I tried this but it will thrown 403 error from google

According to your description, you should firstly make sure you have enable the people api inside the OAuth consent screen then create the oauth clinet and ue it, details you could follow this article.
